# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero in osmnx sub_graph

Tags: osmnx

I am a new python user and I am trying to create a sub_graph based in isochrones. The basic stats report return with an error ( ZeroDivisionError: division by zero ). I guess there is a zero-length edge. How can I exclude those from the seb_graph selection?

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

city = 'Ponta Grossa'
country = 'Brazil'
loc = -25.095, -50.16194
travel_speed = 4.5 
trip_times = [30] 

G = ox.graph_from_point(loc, distance=5000, simplify=True, network_type='drive')
gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
point_of_interest = ox.get_nearest_node(G, point=loc)
G = ox.project_graph(G)

meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60 #km per hour to m per minute
for u, v, k, data in G.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data['time'] = data['length'] / meters_per_minute

subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, point_of_interest, radius=trip_times[0], distance='time') 
basic_stats = ox.basic_stats(subgraph, clean_intersects=True, circuity_dist='euclidean')
```